# Find newline in Notepad++ using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Suppose you have this file:

```
x
a
b
c
x
x
a
b
c
x
x
```

and I want to convert this into -

```
x,a,b,c,x,x,a,b,c,x,x
```

What regular expressions I should use in notepad++. I tried using `\n` in `Find what` but it  didn't find anything somehow.

**UPDATE:-**

Image -

[image]

Comment: `(\r\n||\n)` sounds like youre on Windows

Comment: Doesn't work either. yes I am on windows.

Comment: \r\n works if you are in 'Extended' mode.  If you need to use regex specifically for some reason, you want [\r\n]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other users' answers `\n` or `\r\n` both work as well in my tests, are you sure you have Regex enabled?

[image: Screenshot of Notepad++ testing users request]
[image]

Comment: @user2809564 what happens if you click Find All In Current Document?

Comment: it doesn't find anything

Comment: somehow, it doesn't work in my laptop but same thing works in desktop.. don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

N++ uses PCRE syntax and can therefore tap into `\R`.
Tested and working:

Find what: `\R`

Replace with: `,`

Do make sure to check the `Regular expression` radio button at the bottom left.

Answer (score 3):

To match a newline with notepad++ you can use either: `\r?\n` or `\R`